# Using php tag in image tag

Tags: php, codeigniter

The img tag is not retrieving image at my page.

```
<img class="actar" src=".'<'.'?php echo base_url('/image.jpg')?>'.">
```

But think it is correct code. Image location is a problem. I want to use `base_url()` in img tag and class too.

Give your suggestions

Comment: `src="<?php echo base_url('/image.jpg'); ?>"`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid You forgot the `;` after last `)`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to generate a string containing PHP code. You should provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this :

```
/*make sure image path is correct */

<img class="actar" src="<?=base_url('image.jpg');?>">
```

You can also use `img` from the CI `html helper` like this (**Alternative way**)

In  `autoload.php` load html helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html');
```

In your views :

```
<?php 
    echo img(['class' => 'actar','src' => 'image.jpg']);

    /* Or do like this */

    $data = ['class' => 'actar','src' => 'image.jpg'];
    echo img($data);
?>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img

Answer (score 0):

Try to using below code

```
<img class="actar" src="<?php echo base_url('/image.jpg');?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<img class="actar" src="<?php echo base_url('image.jpg'); ?>">
```

> **Most of the time base url set with `/` at end `https://stackoverflow.com/` so you'll get `https://stackoverflow.com//image.jpg` if you used `/image.jpg`. so remove `/` from `img` tag**

And make sure

1. `image.jpg` is in your project root
2. `base_url` not empty and its set properly

Instead of adding `image.jpg` in the root, add it inside assets(new folder) and move. In case if you need, you can prevent URL access to the folder

Answer (score 0):

> use this code after bese url you add your path

**html**

```
<img class="actar" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>html/images/img1.jpg">
```